# can not connect my android phone to ubuntu

Tags: usb, android, ftp, file-sharing

I am using a android phone with android 10

I plug the device on my laptop, using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS,

and select file transfer and averything ok

but when I click in the device this error pops up:

[error when I try to access the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik3Wm.png)

and when I use the lsusb command:

[the cell phone is detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7FKo.png)

I even try filezilla on my laptop and installed ftp on my cellphone and configured it and all ok,I was able to connect the devices but my phone doesn t show nothing

I run out of ideas

EDIT: On my phone I changed the transfer option and selected pictures transfer and is able to detect the folder with pictures on it

as a conclusion I know the phone is detected and can be accessed in some folders, but what about the others
?

Answer (score 0):

I installed nemo and it could access to all the drives of my phone